# Dealing random JSON key use Gson

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

My json:

```
{
    random1:{ 
      randomKey1:{
          "id":"a", 
          "name":"jack"
      }, 
      randomKey2:{
          "id":"b", 
          "name":"alice"
      }
    },
    random2:{
       randomKey1:{
          "id":"c", 
          "name":"paul"
      }
    }
}
```

Each of my json objects also contains objects.

I use Gson to deserialize. But not my expected result.

I hope to deserialize it output `Map<String, Map<String, Any>>`

I use `JsonDeserializer` to implement. But there is a problem when `for` loop.

```
for ((key, element) in jsonObject.entrySet()) {
   for ((key2, element2) in element.asJsonObject.entrySet()) {
      result2[key2] = element2
   }
   result[key] = result2
}
```

Output is always

```
{random1={randomKey1={value}, randomKey2={value}, randomKey3={value}}, random2={randomKey1={value}}}
```

Expected output

```
{random1={randomKey1={value}, randomKey2={value}}, random2={randomKey1={value}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an object type hashmap which is iterated one by one all key so it takes dynamic keys from JSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String,Map<String, String>> map = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("Put YOur JSOn Here "), mapType);
```

// show value

```
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
String key = entry.getKey();
String value = entry.getValue();
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: Please include some explanation about how your code works so the asker may learn from your answer - thanks!

Comment: its object type hashmap which is iterate one by one all key 
so it take dynamic keys from json 
please up vote or feedback if code helpful for you

Comment: How do I get my "id" or "name"?

Comment: view my edited answer and please don't forgot up vote if its helpful